# Reopening PouchDB in a second Angular factory results in Pouch not using SQLite plugin

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, pouchdb

I'm writing an Ionic app that uses PouchDB and the SQLite plugin. I have a factory responsible for opening the db and exposing some methods for getting records etc:

```
.factory('PouchdbFactory', ['$q', function ($q) {

        var db,
            codes = [];

        var initDB = function() {
            db = new PouchDB('codes', {adapter: 'websql', auto_compaction: true, location: 2}); // location should be 2
            // Listen for changes on the database
            db.changes({ live: true, since: 'now', include_docs: true}).on('change', onDatabaseChange);

            db.info().then(console.log.bind(console));
        }
...etc...
```

And another factory that returns methods that are used to periodically get the records and change them.

```
 .factory('OtpFactory', ['$rootScope', '$interval', 'PouchdbFactory',  function($rootScope, $interval, PouchdbFactory) {

        var otpCodes,
            globalTimerPromise,
            totpObj = new TOTP();

        // this breaks sqllite plugin (db.info().then(console.log.bind(console)); returns sqlite_plugin: false )
        PouchdbFactory.initDB();

        PouchdbFactory.getAllCodes().then(function(codes) {
            otpCodes = codes;
        });
```

Calling `PouchdbFactory.initDB();` in the second factory results in pouch not using the SQLite plugin (`db.info().then(console.log.bind(console));` returns `sqlite_plugin: false`).

I'm still learning Angular, so perhaps this is not the way to structure it. I could move the db creation into `$rootscope` so the database can be access in all factories but I don't understand why calling `PouchdbFactory.initDB();` a second time means no sqlite_plugin.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not that it's the reason for the error, but I would rather just return the db instance if it's initialized. Try a guard clause in init that's checks db has been initialized - if it has the return db straight away, if not then continue to initialize it.